# Как просто распарсить response в php

Tags: php, json

Ко мне приходит следующий response. Мне нужно его распарсить и записать в базу данных с такими полями event_id, title, с fields все поля title превратить в строку, с answers все в строку но там разный тип даных. Вот мой код.

```
<?php 
echo 1;

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$json= file_get_contents('php://input');

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);


$event_id = '';
$title = '';
$answers = '';

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
      if ($key == "event_id"){
    $event_id = $val . ' $$$ '; 
      }

      if ($key == "title"){
    $title = $title . $val . ' $$$ ' ;
      }

      if ($key == "answers"){
    $answers == $answers . $;
      }

}

mail("moy.email","My subject", $answers );


?>
```

Проблема с выводом в строку поля answers. И не могу розиратись, как это правильно сделать. ниже код responce.

```
{
        "event_id": "LtWXD3crgy",
        "event_type": "form_response",
        "form_response": {
            "form_id": "lT4Z3j",
            "token": "a3a12ec67a1365927098a606107fac15",
            "submitted_at": "2018-01-18T18:17:02Z",
            "landed_at": "2018-01-18T18:07:02Z",
            "calculated": {
                "score": 9
            },
            "definition": {
                "id": "lT4Z3j",
                "title": "Webhooks example",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "id": "DlXFaesGBpoF",
                        "title": "Thanks, {{answer_60906475}}! What's it like where you live? Tell us in a few sentences.",
                        "type": "long_text",
                        "ref": "[readable_ref_long_text",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SMEUb7VJz92Q",
                        "title": "If you're OK with our city management following up if they have further questions, please give us your email address.",
                        "type": "email",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_email",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "JwWggjAKtOkA",
                        "title": "What is your first name?",
                        "type": "short_text",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_short_text",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "KoJxDM3c6x8h",
                        "title": "When did you move to the place where you live?",
                        "type": "date",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_date",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "PNe8ZKBK8C2Q",
                        "title": "Which pictures do you like? You can choose as many as you like.",
                        "type": "picture_choice",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_picture_choice",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": true,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Q7M2XAwY04dW",
                        "title": "On a scale of 1 to 5, what rating would you give the weather in Sydney? 1 is poor weather, 5 is excellent weather",
                        "type": "number",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_number1",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "gFFf3xAkJKsr",
                        "title": "By submitting this form, you understand and accept that we will share your answers with city management. Your answers will be anonymous will not be shared.",
                        "type": "legal",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_legal",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "k6TP9oLGgHjl",
                        "title": "Which of these cities is your favorite?",
                        "type": "multiple_choice",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_multiple_choice",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "RUqkXSeXBXSd",
                        "title": "Do you have a favorite city we haven't listed?",
                        "type": "yes_no",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_yes_no",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "NRsxU591jIW9",
                        "title": "How important is the weather to your opinion about a city? 1 is not important, 5 is very important.",
                        "type": "opinion_scale",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_opinion_scale",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "WOTdC00F8A3h",
                        "title": "How would you rate the weather where you currently live? 1 is poor weather, 5 is excellent weather.",
                        "type": "rating",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_rating",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "pn48RmPazVdM",
                        "title": "On a scale of 1 to 5, what rating would you give the general quality of life in Sydney? 1 is poor, 5 is excellent",
                        "type": "number",
                        "ref": "readable_ref_number2",
                        "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                        "allow_other_choice": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "answers": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "It's cold right now! I live in an older medium-sized city with a university. Geographically, the area is hilly.",
                    "field": {
                        "id": "DlXFaesGBpoF",
                        "type": "long_text"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "email",
                    "email": "laura@example.com",
                    "field": {
                        "id": "SMEUb7VJz92Q",
                        "type": "email"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Laura",
                    "field": {
                        "id": "JwWggjAKtOkA",
                        "type": "short_text"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "date",
                    "date": "2005-10-15",
                    "field": {
                        "id": "KoJxDM3c6x8h",
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "choices",
                    "choices": {
                        "labels": [
                            "London",
                            "Sydney"
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": {
                        "id": "PNe8ZKBK8C2Q",
                        "type": "picture_choice"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 5,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "Q7M2XAwY04dW",
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "boolean": true,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "gFFf3xAkJKsr",
                        "type": "legal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "choice",
                    "choice": {
                        "label": "London"
                    },
                    "field": {
                        "id": "k6TP9oLGgHjl",
                        "type": "multiple_choice"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "boolean": false,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "RUqkXSeXBXSd",
                        "type": "yes_no"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 2,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "NRsxU591jIW9",
                        "type": "opinion_scale"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 3,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "WOTdC00F8A3h",
                        "type": "rating"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 4,
                    "field": {
                        "id": "pn48RmPazVdM",
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

---

```
{
        "type": "choices",
        "choices": {
          "labels": [
            "What am I doing or talking about when you experience me MOST energized and happy?",
            "What reliably shows up in the room when I enter?"
          ]
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "fTQS65h4ZUe9",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "74f0e30e-ba59-49ef-a2c1-22a79c0ac0ca"
        }
      },
```

есть проблема, не парсить отдельно

```
    $fields_answers = array_map(function($v){
                  if($v['type'] == 'choices'){
                       return $v['choices']['labels'];
                  }
          if($v['type'] == 'text'){
                       return $v['text'];
                  } 
          if($v['type'] == 'email'){
                       return $v['email'];
                  }   
          if($v['type'] == 'date'){
                       return $v['date'];
                  }
          if($v['type'] == 'number'){
                       return $v['number'];
                  }
          if($v['type'] == 'boolean'){
                       return $v['boolean'];
                  }  
                  return $v[ $v['type'] ];
             }, $object["form_response"]["answers"]);
$answers = implode("***", $fields_answers);
```

Получаю Array

Comment: вы для данного примера напишите, какой результат хотите получить. а то итератор и проверка имен ключей это бред какой то

Comment: Вы правы, в результате я хочу получить следующее. event_id, title, строку в которой будут все title из field и строку в которой будут все ответы с answers. Эти данные я хочу записать в базу.

Comment: ответы это `text` из `answers`?

Comment: зачем вы написали эти if-ы с `$v['type'] == 'text'` ?

Comment: потому, что надо парсить с json ответы разных типов, все работает кроме choises.

Comment: оно и без этого работало. если у вас `$v['type']` равно `'text'` то выражения `return $v['text']` будет эквивалентно `return $v[ $v['type'] ]` и так для всех ваших date, email, number, boolean. поэтому и было одна строка с return. Случай с choices был описан отдельно. там возвращается массив. Если с этим массивом вам надо что-то сделать, то и добавьте `return implode("\n", $v['choices']['labels']);` например, или то что вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть у вас json, раскодировали вы его в

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Чтобы получить первый идентификатор взяли просто

```
$eventId = $data['event_id'];
```

С `title` чуть дольше но все так же просто:

```
$title = $data['definition']['title'];
```

чтобы получить все `fields.title` можно сделать так

```
$fields = array_column($data['definition']['fields'], 'title');
```

это будет массив. Если хотите собрать его в одну строку, то используйте, например

```
$fieldsStr = implode("\n", $fields)
```

С ответами ситуация аналогичная,   `array_column($data['answers'], 'text')`.

Если вы и это все хотите сложить в единую строку, то

```
$result = "$event_id|$title|$fieldsStr|....";
```

непонятно, правда, зачем вам это надо.

---

Дополнение к `answers`. Поскольку возвращаемое значение зависит от поля `type`, то используем

```
$answers = array_map(function($v){
                  if($v['type'] == 'choice'){
                       return $v['choice']['label'];
                  }    
                  return $v[ $v['type'] ];
             }, $data['answers']);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Есть только одна проблема, ответ не всегда текст. Это берется из поля type. Может быть email, number и тд.

Comment: @MykolaDan дополнил, примерно.

Comment: Спасибо)))))))))

Comment: Заметил что нужно добавить ["form_response"] еще

Comment: А можете еще пожалуйста объяснить, как работает код с answers?

Comment: @MykolaDan `array_map` перебирает элементы входящего массива, и вовзращает их в измененом виде. В вашем случае, вам надо вернуть поле `text`, `email`, `number` и т.п. в зависимости от того, что указано в `type`. Поскольку значение `type` совпадает с именем поля, то мы просто возвращаем `$v[ $v['type'] ]`. Если бы не совпадало, то написали бы `switch`. Собственно в случае `choices` и не совпадает, так что оно рассматривается отдельно.

Comment: Добавил ещо вопрос

Comment: @MykolaDan во первых не ясно, что вам там хотите спросить, во-вторых , возможно, лучше таки задать новый вопрос